# OAuth2 not working

Tags: support, bug, login, oauth2

Today I'm unable to log in to my web application with Stack Overflow OAuth2.

I receive the following error on Keycloak:

> 2023-09-22 12:46:28,800 ERROR [org.keycloak.broker.oidc.AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider] (executor-thread-1865) Failed to make identity provider oauth callback: org.keycloak.broker.provider.IdentityBrokerException: No access token available in OAuth server response: `<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en-US"><head><title>Just a moment...</title><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"><meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><link href="/cdn-cgi/styles/challenges.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body class="no-js"><div class="main-wrapper" role="main"><div`

LinkedIn, Google, FB, GitHub OAuth2 providers work fine.

Keycloak version: `18.0.2`

Has anything changed for Stack Overflow OAuth2?

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393039/stack-exchange-network-sites-ip-addresses-may-change-in-the-coming-weeks

Comment: It could be that you're getting an intermittent response from CloudFlare: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393116/every-site-requesting-verification-that-im-human

Comment: I'm a bit curious how you use keycloak here. Is keycloak handling the authentication for the app?

Comment: It worked throughout the whole year, and today, for some reason, it stopped working

Comment: @rene I use Keycloak as the Single Sign-On (SSO) server for my app. On the Keycloak side, I have configured various Identity Providers (IdPs) such as Google, Facebook, StackOverflow, and so on

Comment: Might be related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392172/se-api-recent-oauth-2-0-implicit-flow-breaking-change

Comment: I have no idea what I can do with this because Keycloak is a black box to me, and I can't change anything there

Comment: @alexanoid I actually went and looked into Keycloak's code. If I am reading things right the change in the response containing the scope won't break Keycloak. Looking at the error you get it also gives you the response the access token endpoint should have given to Keycloak, the title of it is "Just a moment..." so it seems you might be hitting CloudFlare like rene mentioned. Although putting bot protection on an API created to be used by bots does sound like a weird thing for SE to do.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat thanks. I changed the CloudFlare DNS record settings for my 'sso' subdomain from 'Proxied' to 'DNS only', but it didn't help.

Comment: Your settings for CloudFlare won't help. It's Stack Overflow's settings that are the problem. Keycloak needs to call their API for getting the access token but is hitting CloudFlare in the process. See the url rene linked in their second comment.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you! It seems like I have no choice but to temporarily disable it until the SO dev team fixes this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the report, pushing out a fix now.

Comment: @alexanoid the fix is live, can you see if it resolved your issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, the same issue is still present

Comment: @alexanoid I'd like to isolate your traffic, are you getting a RayID in that response? If so I can use that to find the exact request.

Comment: I see only the following param with `ray` - `cRay: '80aba202fd894c78'`

Comment: @alexanoid that looks correct, is that from your latest attempt? Odd I can't find it in the logs.

Comment: It was from previous attempts; then I disabled the StackOverflow IdP. I have now re-enabled it and tried one more time. Received cRay: '80abf46c4a7ad906'

Comment: You can also try it on the website https://decisionwanted.com If you try to log in through StackOverflow, you will receive this error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255385/discussion-between-josh-zhang-and-alexanoid).